# Solving addition chain problems using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

You are given a positive integer A. The goal is to construct the shortest possible sequence of integers ending with A, using the following rules:

1. The first element of the sequence is 1
2. Each of the successive elements is the sum of any two preceding elements (adding a single element to itself is also permissible)
3. Each element is larger than all the preceding elements; that is, the sequence is increasing.

For example, for A = 42, a possible solution is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24, 30, 42]
```

Another possible solution for A = 42 is:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 16, 21, 42]
```

After reading the problem statement, the first thing that came to my mind is [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) (DP), hence I expressed it as a [search problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem) and tried to write a recursive solution.

The search space up to A = 8 is:

```
                1
                |
                2
               / \
              /   \            
             3     4
            /|\   /|\
           / | \ 5 6 8
          /  |  \
         4   5   6
       /| |\  
      5 6 7 8
```

We can see that 4 occurs in two places, but in both cases the children of 4 are different. In one case the prior sequence is [1, 2, 4]. In the other case the prior sequence is [1, 2, 3, 4]. Therefore, we cannot say that we have overlapping sub-problems. Is there any way to apply DP to the above problem? Or I am wrong in judging that it can be solve using DP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an **addition chain**...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain

> There is no known algorithm which can calculate a
>   minimal addition chain for a given number with any guarantees of
>   reasonable timing or small memory usage. However, several techniques
>   to calculate relatively short chains exist. One very well known
>   technique to calculate relatively short addition chains is the **binary
>   method**, similar to exponentiation by squaring. Other well-known
>   methods are the **factor method** and **window method**.

See also: [New Methods For Generating Short Addition Chains](https://search.ieice.org/bin/summary.php?id=e83-a_1_60) in IEICE Transactions on Fundamentals of Electronics, Communications and Computer Sciences.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure dynamic programming solution to this problem.  But as all DP solutions, the complexity for both memory and time is N squared.  So it can be a space hog.  But here is the crux of the DP solution just for DP lovers:

## Generalization:

Instead of finding the min length of addition chain for N viz. l(N), we are to find the min length of addition chain that contains both i and j with i ≤ j and j being max in the chain.  Call this length A(i, j).  Obviously, we have

1. l(N) = A(1, N) = A(N,N)
2. A(1, N) = A(2, N) if N ≥ 2
3. A(1, N) = 1+min (A(i, j) for 1 ≤ i ≤ j < N and i+j=N

## Advance Calculation

To calculate any A(m, n) by using smaller A(i, j), a typical DP step, we apply a number of heuristics.

**H1:** maintain an S(i+j) for the min part of the (3) along the way.  Then

```
 A(1, n) = A(2, n) = A(n, n) = S(n)+1
```

For other m, we reduce n by introducing at most one more new element to the chain, and with such a new element, we just need one more step to conclude A(m, n).  Possibilities are

**H2:** if n is even, we attempt to introduce n/2 to the chain 
**H3:** attempt to introduce n-m to the chain 
**H4:** attempt to introduce n-1 to the chain 
**H5:** attempt to introduce n-2 to the chain (when n>2)

So A(m, n) to take the min of A of m and the reduced n based on H2-H5, plus 1.

Example, A(52, 100) = 1+min(A(50, 52), A(48, 52), A(52, 99), A(52, 98)) by applying H2-H5 respectively.

Comment: This statement is not accurate: "But as all DP solutions, the complexity for both memory and time is N squared." DP solutions vary.

Comment: In mathematical proofs, I would recommend against saying "Obviously, we have... [list of equations]".  See https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1896  Many would not find "A(1,N) = 1+min (A(i,j) for 1 ≤ i ≤ j < N and i+j=N" to be obvious. Two examples would help many people, one even and one odd; `A(1,8) = 1 + min { A(1,7), A(2,6), A(3,5), A(4,4) }` and `A(1,7) = 1 + min { A(1,6), A(2,5), A(3,4) }`. These examples give the reader a clearer idea of why the A(i,j) construct is elegant; it handles both the even and odd cases in the same way.

Comment: Clarification question what do you mean by the "Advance Calculation" heading? Is this a typo? Do you mean "advanced calculation" as in "improved calculation" due to heuristics?

Comment: I'd like to see the "Generalization" section include another equation: the recurrence relation for A(i, j) in general (where i is not 1). Without it, the overall recurrence relation is incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

Due to rule #2,

> Each of the successive elements is the sum of any two preceding elements

The algorithm does rely on duplicate subproblems, so Dynamic Programming would be suitable for solving it.

Comment: No, because there are several possible solutions to the subproblem and we don't know which one to use.  Ref rule #3